# 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

Tags: django, django-authentication

I know there are similar questions like this, and I tried every solution that is adressed in those questions. Here is my problem described;

When I execute createsuperuser, I got an error as follows;

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

Here is how I define UserAccountManager and UserAccount in my implementation;

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email must be set!')
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def get_by_natural_key(self, email_):
        return self.get(code_number=email_)


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # default=False when you are going to implement Activation Mail
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return  self.email

    def has_perms(self, perm, ob=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        self.is_admin
```

I set object as follows in UserAccount class : objects = UserAccountManager

What do I do wrong?

Edit (to address Iain Shelvington's solution):
in settings.py, I have this line;

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'
```

Comment: You should change `objects = UserAccountManager` to `objects = UserAccountManager()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `objects = UserAccountManager()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the setting [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) to `'your_app.UserAccount'`

Comment: it is already set as AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'